# Unintialized variable but I'm trying to accept an input for a variable?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to set up an input that takes in a price and quantity of an item and it keeps giving me the uninitialized variable error for both of them so I give them a variable of 0 under the main and yet it won't print out the input and just shows their value to be 0?

```
int main() {

string partNumber;
string partDiscription;
int partQuantity = 0;
int partPrice = 0;
int getInvoiceAmount;
class Invoice;

cout << "Please enter part number: " << partNumber << endl;
getline(cin, partNumber);
cout << "Please enter part discription: " << partDiscription << endl;
getline(cin, partDiscription);
cout << "Please enter quantity of item: " << partQuantity << endl;
cin >> partQuantity;
cout << "Please enter price of item: " << partPrice << endl;

if (partQuantity < 0)
    partQuantity = 0;
if (partPrice < 0)
    partPrice = 0;
```

Comment: That is not an error, but a warning. Presumably. But you're not showing us verbatim so we can only guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are attempting to cout the variable's data before they have been initialized. You should do this instead

```
cout << "Please enter part number: " << endl;
getline(cin, partNumber);
cout << "Please enter part discription: " << endl;
getline(cin, partDiscription);
cout << "Please enter quantity of item: " << endl;
cin >> partQuantity;
```

This way you aren't trying to reference a variable that has yet to be initialized.